How to create a calculated column that is the sum of values from another table grouped by similar column value?
Data Table:



Color
Amount




Red
5


Blue
3


Red
5


Blue
6



Main Table:



Color
Count




Red
10


Blue
9


Green
0



Hello I have two tables that deal with gumballs let's say, and I am trying to make a calculated column called "Count" in my Main Table that will basically sum all the amounts of gumballs from Data Table grouped by color. Data Table is available to me, and I am showing what I want the Main Table to look like.
What I tried so far: I established a one to many relationship in modal view for color in main table to color in data table.
Count = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(RELATED(DATA_TABLE[Amount])),
        MAIN_TABLE[Color] = RELATED(DATA_TABLE[Color])
    ) 

This is the DAX expression I tried but anything after "Related" is underlined red and it says "Parameter is not the correct type / Cannot find name '[Amount]' / Cannot find name '[Color]'" and now I'm not sure what to do. I am making this calculated column in the Main Table.

make sure you have created the relationship between two tables and try this to create a column
Column = CALCULATE( sum('Data'[Amount]))+0


